# Why my django localhost server does not restart after modification in my code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code, localhost

In all my django projects on Visual Studio Code, the server localhost django refreshes automatically after modification in my code.
I'm using a venv with python 3.10.8 and I'm using autosave.
I don't know if it's because of external libraries. I haven't found any other solutions.

I tried:

- -m pip install django-browser-reload
- python manage.py collectstatic
- solve the problems in the "Problems" tab by updating the interpreter of my venv

Despite this, each python code modify, add, delete, stop the server and restart it not like the behavior before.

Comment: you need to be running live server.